# How to open .dbml in designer mode with VS?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

After installing Visual Studio 2017, my LINQ To SQL `.dbml` definitions open in a XML editor instead of the built in designer.

How do I configure VS to open `.dbml` in Designer mode instead of XML editor?

Comment: do you have any other versions of VS on that box?

Comment: Yes I do have a Vs 2013 and `dbml` open in designer mode.

Comment: I've had issues with some designers when installing multiple versions of VS. For instance, when I installed 2012 next to 2010, all my DB designers started failing (much as you describe). The two versions used a pair of dlls of differant versions stored in the same location. Even uninstalling 2012 did not fix it; I had to copy the dlls from a coworkers box who had not installed 2012 in order to get 2010 working again.

Comment: FYI: The same problem exists in VS 2019. Also the solution provided by Coxy works equivalently

Answer (score 185, accepted):

1. Quit devenv
2. Launch `Visual Studio Installer`
3. Modify VS2017
   [image]
4. Click on the `Individual components` tab and scroll down to `LINQ to SQL tools` (within `Code tools` group.)
   [image]
5. Click `Modify`.
6. Launch devenv again and you should be able to open `.dbml` in the designer we all love to hate.

Comment: Thanks. I used the quick launch (CTRL+Q), typed linq to sql and found it.